# Compare two dates with method validator in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i want to compare two dates of start and end.

Here my jquery method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan",
    function (value, element, params) {
        if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
            return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
        }
}, 'Date end must be greater than date start !');
```

Here's my parameters with values after executing :

```
DateStart = "03/07/2018"
DateEnd = "15/07/2021"
value = DateEnd
$(params).val() = DateStart
```

The first problem is that - below condition is always false which i don't understand why. As here value is my `DateEnd` which is "15/07/2021" :

```
if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)))
```

My second problem is that - below condition is always false despite that my `DateEnd` is greater than my `DateStart` :

```
new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val())
```

So how can i solve these problems.

Comment: Those aren't valid date strings to pass to new Date

Comment: @charlietfl so what i do to make them valid

Comment: Would need to parse strings to pass as `new Date(year,month,day)`. Keep in mind months are zero indexed. --OR-- Have source provide them as proper ISO formatted strings or timestamps

Comment: You should use the `datepicker` for bootstrap and jquery to work with the dates and time. Try a bit search and you will know, what i am trying to say.

Comment: can someone write an exemple

Comment: If you are certain of format just use `split('/')` to get array and use array elements for date arguments and subtract one from month